# ScalaIDE: code formatting

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

When I was editing my Java code, I could simply press `Ctrl+Shift+F` and get my code autoformatted.

Now I'm using ScalaIDE and I found out no option to format the code on-demand. I didn't even found such an option when I searched the `Keys` section of the preferences. Can you please show me where the option is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is same in ScalaIDE, see [here](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/typingviewing/formatting/index.html). It uses [Scalariform](https://github.com/scala-ide/scalariform) internally, where you can specify your settings(Window -> Preferences -> Scala -> Editor -> Formatter). Ctrl+Shift+F works also, check your Eclipse shortcuts again.